# Annotation not working

Tags: java, ant, annotations

I'm working on an annotation which aims to it mandatory for a class to be immutable. Here the code of the processor:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("archipel.immutability.IsImmutable")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)
public class IsImmutableProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
            RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (TypeElement type : annotations) {
            processMustBeImmutable(roundEnv, type);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void processMustBeImmutable(RoundEnvironment env, TypeElement type) {
        for (Element element : env.getElementsAnnotatedWith(type)) {
            processClass(element);
        }
    }

    private void processClass(Element element) {
        boolean isFinal=false;

        for(Modifier modifier : element.getModifiers()) {
            if (modifier.equals(Modifier.FINAL)) {
                isFinal=true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isFinal) {
            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Class "+element+" is not immutable because it is not final");
        } else {
            for (Element subElement : element.getEnclosedElements()) {
                if (subElement.getKind()==ElementKind.FIELD) {
                    isFinal=false;

                    for(Modifier modifier : subElement.getModifiers()) {
                        if (modifier.equals(Modifier.FINAL)) {
                            isFinal=true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isFinal) {
                        processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Field "+element+" is not immutable because it is not final");
                    } else {
                        Element superElement = subElement.getEnclosingElement();
                        // TODO
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The annotation itself is trivial, of course:

```
@Inherited
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface IsImmutable {
}
```

And I compile it with a Ant script:

```
<project name="immutability" basedir="." default="main">

    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>

    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>

    <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="meta.dir" value="${build.dir}/META-INF"/>
    <property name="jar.dir" value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

    <property name="processor-package"
        value="archipel.immutability" />

    <property name="processor" value="${processor-package}.IsImmutableProcessor"/>

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="Compiles the code.">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" />
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar">
            <fileset dir="${classes.dir}"/>
            <service type="javax.annotation.processing.Processor" provider="archipel.immutability.IsImmutableProcessor"/>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="main" depends="clean,jar"/>

</project>
```

Problem is, something must be missing, because when I try to use the resulting annotation, provided by the resulting jar file, like the following, nothing happens:

```
@IsImmutable
public class Immut {

    private int toto;

    public int getToto() {
        return toto;
    }

    public void setToto(int toto) {
        this.toto = toto;
    }

    public final static void main(String args[]) {
        Immut truc = new Immut();
        truc.setToto(5);
        truc.setToto(6);
    }

}
```

Obviousy, this class is not final, and the class should signal an error in Eclipse. But it's not.

Any idea?

**Edit**: The jar file I built with my build.xml seems correct: It contains the class files, and also a `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` file, which contains `archipel.immutability.IsImmutableProcessor`. I import this jar file in my test project, and when I use the annotation in my Immut class (which is only a rough test), nothing happens.

Comment: ...Just to check: you're aware that not all immutable classes will pass your test?  `java.lang.String` won't, for example.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. It's a work in progress, at this point.

Comment: So I put a bounty on this question, but nobody is suggesting any answer. Are there really so few people with knowledge on annotation processing? That would not only be annoying for my very problem, but also kind of worrying for the future of Java technology: My question is not about some vague API but about a central feature of the JDK...

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but you can use the `@Immutable` annotation from [Java Concurrency in Practice (JCiP)](http://jcip.net/annotations/doc/net/jcip/annotations/package-summary.html) together with [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) to perform basic immutability tests on classes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Annotation processing by default is disabled in eclipse. in order to enable it you need to open project properties and then 
1. Java Compiler -> Annotation processing: enable annotation processing
2. Java Compiler -> Annotation processing -> factory path: add jar with factories

if you need some more information take a look at: [getting started with AP in eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_apt_getting_started.htm)

**Edited:**

take a look at this [tutorial](http://kerebus.com/2011/02/using-java-6-processors-in-eclipse/). It explains in details how to set up eclipse to use custom annotation processors.

Important: when printing errors use this method:  `javax.annotation.processing.Messager.printMessage(Kind, CharSequence, Element)`
instead of:
`javax.annotation.processing.Messager.printMessage(Kind, CharSequence).`

messages from the first one are visible in Problems view and most source-related views while messages from the second one are visible only in ErrorLog view.

Comment: I think I was not clear enough in my question. The annotation and the processir are contained in a jar file, which configuration seems correct. I edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Ok, it seems you're right. I tried to use Lombok, which also uses RetentionPolicy.SOURCE annotations, and they don't work either. But I still don't get what to do to make it work. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I gave you the 50 bounty points. No need to let them go to waste, and at least, you pointed me in the right direction...

Comment: The `printMessage` detail saved my life, coudlnt' found that information anywhere else!

Comment: a note to help maven users: there's no need to do this manual setup step when you install the m2e-apt connector: see [How to run JSR269 annotation processor in Eclipse Kepler with Java 7 & Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19399222/1041641)

Comment: Where to find the .jar files e.g. for @JavaScript annotation?

Answer (score 0):

probably it is worth to use **cglib** to make you object immutable. because imagine that you have a collection inside your class and collection field is final. You have also getter for this collection. does it mean that collection can't be modified outside teh class? not exactly. Only if this collection was wrapped with **Collections.unmodifiedCollection** method.
Or if you are using guava immutable collections http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained

The point is - don't try to hanle this only be checking whether fields are final - it will not handle all scenarios. use **cglib** proxy instead like **spring and hibernate** does

Comment: My question is about annotation and how to make a RetentionLevel.SOURCE annotation processor work in Eclipse. I'm aware Guava is offering immutable collections, but that's not the point, here.

Comment: then the previous response provides useful links.. i just tried to make a point that immutability checking is something that can't be achieved with just checking whether fields are final. in groovy immutability implemented so well http://groovy.codehaus.org/Immutable+AST+Macro - when would we have the same in java?)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm trying to solve MY problem here. If you want to talk about Guava or Groovy, you're in the wrong place. Do you think I would offer a bounty if the already existing anwser had solved my problem?

Comment: i thought you have found the answer from the Tomasz Krzyżak response - did you?

Comment: Tomasz Krzyżak's got me further but didn't solve my problem, as you can see in my comments.